# Chartjs how to disable a scale in stacked line chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js, linechart

I tried to hide an axis in stacked line chart, it kinda works but the area stays there.
How can I delete that area in the picture and connect the other axises between.
Thanks in advance!

[image: Line Chart]

```js
y3: {
    type: "linear",
    position: "left",
    stack: "demo",
    display: false,
    stackWeight: 1,
    },
```

Comment: It's unclear why would you keep `y3` if there's no data associated with it. The best solution appears to be to just remove `y3` from `scales`.  If you can't do that for some reason, you can reduce the allocated space by decreasing the `stackWeight` - not zero because that will create problems, but something like `stackWeight: 0.01` should work.

Comment: @kikon i tried it and didn't work, there is still a space. The thought behind this i want  to display and hide some y axises on user selection and get it the axis back if user want it.

Comment: That space should be minimal, and possibly reduced with even a smaller `stackWeight`; on the other hand, the scenario you describe involves calls to [`chart.update()`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#updating-charts), so the best solution is to modify the logic of your application that instead of changing `stackWeight`, just  remove `y3` from `options.scales` before update, if it is not needed, and add it if it *is* needed. You'll get more specific answers, in code, iff you post your full code, or a runnable extract of it, which is almost always a good idea on SO.

Comment: That helped well !! I guess I forgot to call update function. Thank you @kikon

Answer (score 0):

```
const options = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
    ],
```